# Parsing html in win8 store app using linq and Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, linq, windows-store-apps

I am C# XAML and Linq beginner and I need help parsing this html code using linq. I know how to get values between strong> tags using linq but i need to extract values between td class= 'sivo' and get that english name of the movie, and get its links and corresponding playing times which are displayed after https links.

```
<div class='movieItemWrapper'>
       <table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='0'>
           <tr>
             <td>
                  <strong>Riddick</strong>
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td class='sivo'>Riddick</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class='sivo'>DV. 11  -
                    <a href='https://some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=C9A53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>16.50</a>, DV. 11  - <a href='https://some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=20B53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>19.15</a>, DV. 7  - <a href='https://some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=41B53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>20.00</a>, DV. 11  - <a href='https://some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=05B53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>21.40</a>, DV. 7  - <a href='https://some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=86B53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>22.30</a>,
                </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </div>
        <div class='movieItemWrapper'>
           <table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='0'>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <strong>Domestic name</strong>
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class='sivo'>The Conjuring</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td class='sivo'>DV. 3  - <a href='https://some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=2AA53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>17.00</a>, DV. 2  - <a href='some.text.here/performance.aspx?oid=4EA53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>19.00</a>, DV. 2  - <a href='https://some.text.here.hr/performance.aspx?oid=E3B53000023KBHTNGF&amp;coid=10000000014OCPXCOG' target='_blank'>21.20</a>,
                 </td>
             </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

i tried this code

```
var times = from tr in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
            from td in tr.Descendants("td").Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "sivo")
            select td;
```

Comment: Any code about what you have tried so far?

Comment: i edited my firs post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc= new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); htmlDoc.LoadHtml(stringWithHtml);        
  var names = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "td").Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "sivo");

    var links = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "td").Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "sivo").Select(x => x.Descendants().Where(s => s.Name == "a"));
    foreach (var item in names)
    {
        var blabla = item.InnerText;
    }
    foreach (var item in links)
    {
        var lnks = item.Select(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value);//links
        var times = item.Select(x => x.InnerText);  //times
    }
```

Comment: Most probably it is correct. Do you think to explain what `DocumentNode` is and how you initiated it.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(stringWithHtml);
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes....

Comment: Thank you for fast replay but the problem is WinRT does not include SelectNodes and i can't use it. I need to use Descendants() functions

Comment: It is in htmlagilitypack

Comment: htmlAgilitypack does not include SelectNodes in Windows Runtime, or WinRT. Try opening new Win8 Store app project and you will see

Comment: for var Names and for var Links i get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Fixed, try to do something by yourself also.

Comment: Thank you. I get the results now.